# when using javascript how do you use select form to do if else statements?

Tags: javascript, select, if-statement

How do you take a value of an option in a select form and use it for a if else statement?

for example if apple is selected as an option then write to the document how to make applesauce but orange is selected then write how to make orange?

so far I have a basic form and select options and I know how to do the document.write but I dont know how to use a select form with if else

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have an `id` on your `<select>` allowing you to reference it from Javascript:

```
<select id="fruits">...</select>
```

Now, you can use the `options` and `selectedIndex` fields on the Javascript representation of your `<select>` to access the current selected value:

```
var fruits = document.getElementById("fruits");
var selection = fruits.options[fruits.selectedIndex].value;

if (selection == "apple") {
    alert("APPLE!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup

```
<select id="Dropdown" >
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Your JavaScript logic

```
if(document.getElementById('Dropdown').options[document.getElementById('Dropdown').selectedIndex].value == "Apple") {
//write applesauce
}
else {
//everything else
}
```

Comment: I think you are mixing things. Looks like you're using jQuery-ish selector functions, but you just wrote "if('#Dropdown')".

Also, use <code>===</code> where possible.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. When I think JavaScript I think jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = document.getElementById('myList');
if (select.value === 'apple') {
  /* Applesauce */
} else if (select.value === 'orange') {
  /* Orange */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do this.

```
var fruitSelection = document.formName.optionName; /* if select has been given an name AND a form have been given a name */
/* or */ 
var fruitSelection = document.getElementById("fruitOption"); /* If <select> has been given an id */

var selectedFruit = fruitSelection.options[fruitSelection.selectedIndex].value;

if (selectedFruit == "Apple") {
  document.write("This is how to make apple sauce....<br />...");
} else {

}
```

//HTML

```
<!-- For the 1st option mentioned above -->

<form name="formName">
  <select name="optionName> <!-- OR -->
  <select id="optionName">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
    <option value="Peach">Peach</option>
  </select>
</form>
```